# Shopify Hydrogen Demo Site Error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='

Tags: node.js, typescript, shopify

I set me up a new site using the demo site for shopify hydrogen as a template, when i try and run it i get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='` error, i'm unsure whats causing the error.

```
9:35:23 PM [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/dist/esnext/entry-server.js?v=dec8cd9a:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
    at new AsyncFunction (<anonymous>)
```

package.json

```
{
  "description": "Demo store template for @shopify/hydrogen",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "shopify hydrogen dev",
    "build": "shopify hydrogen build",
    "preview": "shopify hydrogen preview",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx src",
    "lint-ts": "tsc --noEmit",
    "test": "WATCH=true vitest",
    "test:ci": "yarn build -t node && vitest run"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@shopify/cli": "3.7.1",
    "@shopify/cli-hydrogen": "3.7.1",
    "@shopify/prettier-config": "^1.1.2",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "eslint": "^8.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-hydrogen": "^0.12.2",
    "playwright": "^1.22.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-import": "^14.1.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^7.6.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "vite": "^3.0.8",
    "vitest": "^0.15.2"
  },
  "prettier": "@shopify/prettier-config",
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.6.4",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
    "@shopify/hydrogen": "^1.2.0",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-use": "^17.4.0",
    "title": "^3.4.4",
    "typographic-base": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost", "es2020"],
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": ["vite/client", "vitest/globals"],
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your node version is probably 14 or lower which does not support [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://node.green/#ES2021-features-Logical-Assignment-----basic-support). Shopify hydrogen [requires Node.js version 16.14.0 or higher](https://github.com/Shopify/hydrogen#:%7E:text=16.14.0).